# references not showing up in Quant Finance journal format

Tags: bibliographies, journal

I've been struggling with references. I'm using a format called 'rQUF' distributed by Taylor&Francis. Even with the guide, the tex file failed to import references.

According to the guide, it suffices to use

```
\bibliographystyle{rQUF}
\bibliography{rQUFguide}
```

rQUF.bst and rQUFguide.bib are in the same directory where .tex is located. The code outputs references with only a '0' entry.

[image]

This is the error related to bibliography from Overleaf:

The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.

```
<argument> \@bibsetup 
                      {0}\setcounter {NAT@ctr}{0}
l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{0}
                              
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Idk where to fix at this moment. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: delete the generated files (overleaf has a menu option) if that doesn't work try loading `natbib` which will define `\@bibsetup`,

Comment: Thank you! I figured this error out. The format has its own "natbib.sty" using 'natbib' package, and \@bibsetup wasn't assigned correctly inside the file.

Comment: Could you help me again @DavidCarlisle? I'm struggling with references. Instead of using .bib, I decide to go with a list of \bibitem. (not reading the .bib file even after the error was fixed) Their keys are 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2', etc. Each key is unique, of course. But I've had "./output.aux Package natbib Warning: Citation `B1' multiply defined." error. No .bib file in the directory, and I tried to delete all cached files and re-run the code.

Comment: sorry impossible to guess, you would need to show an example